# Method added to ECMASscript 5th edition, why this conditional check?

Tags: javascript

```
if(typeof Object.create !== "function") {

   Object.create = function(o) {

      function F(){}
      F.prototype = 0;
      return new F();
};
```

Why, `if(typeof Object.create !== "function")` if the method is just being created and as a built in? Why the need to check if it is a function if that is as said being created?

Comment: If `Object.create` does not exist, the `typeof` expression will return "undefined".  If it is, we define it.  You're avoiding re-defining an existing method.

Comment: Unless you want your code to run on very old browsers, that whole code can be ignored and deleted.  It's a polyfill for ES3 browsers, even IE9 doesn't require this.

Answer (score 3):

This tests to see if the JS engine has a native `Object.create` method.

If it does not, then it adds one.

This is to avoid replacing the built-in method (which is likely to be heavily optimised) with one written in JS.

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.create()` method creates a new object, using an existing object to provide the newly created object's ___proto____. -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

That condition checks if `Object.create()` is available for use. In some JS engine, this is not the case so that's why that check is necessary.